# How to create intermediate directories with :w automatically?

Tags: save, autocmd

It happens that you want to save a file in a subdirectory that does
not exist yet, as in

```
:w ~/customers/one-met-today/note.txt
```

when the directory `one-met-today/` does not exist.

In the shell, that would be like running

```
mkdir "$(dirname ~/customers/one-met-today/"
```

before.

It would be great if multiple levels could be created, like in shell

```
mkdir -p "$(dirname ~/customers/one-met-today/notes/offer.txt)"
```

so I can do

```
:w ~/customers/one-met-today/notes/offer.txt
```

in `vim`.

I would prefer using an option for making `:w` just support that.

As alternatives:
what would be the command to solve it with shell `mkdir` without typing the file name twice?
Or maybe use `autocmd` `BufWritePre` and `FileWritePre` before `:w`? But that feels a little unclean, because it modifies basic behaviour in an obscure way.

Comment: On [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4292733/438329)